# Update Variable Dynamically JS

Tags: javascript

I want to update a value of one field using values of other fields with spaces. If value is null, space shouldn't be added. What logic should I use as I can't use IF in value set.

**EXAMPLE**

```
document.getElementById("target").value= Constant+if(name){" "+this.value}+if(age){" "+this.value}+if(height){" "+this.value};
```

Comment: I am using required field so at the end it won't make a difference just want to find a way to learn.

Comment: You can't use an `if` **statement** inside an **expression**. You are looking for the [*conditional operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: I know and I just meant the logic. I said I can't use IF already.

Comment: why not put your code in a function where you CAN use if?

Comment: If you are interested, there are frameworks out there that can do this type of thing for you through binding.  Checkout [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/), [angular.js](https://angularjs.org/), [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your string formatting code in a function where you can use if statements.

```
document.getElementById("target").value = formatValue();

function formatValue(){
    var formattedString = Constant;

    if(name){
        formattedString += " " + name;
    }

    if(age){
        formattedString += " " + age:
    }

    if(height){
        formattedString += " " + height:
    }

    return formattedString;
}
```

If you prefer not to have a named function, use a self-invoking anonymous function:

```
document.getElementById("target").value = (function(){
    var formattedString = Constant;

    if(name){
        formattedString += " " + name;
    }

    if(age){
        formattedString += " " + age:
    }

    if(height){
        formattedString += " " + height:
    }

    return formattedString;
})();
```

Comment: I know you can use another function for formatting ;) That wasn't the point tho. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Odin You can use a self-invoking anonymous function instead.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called a ternary operator.  A boolean condition followed by `?` with the `true` value to return and after `:` the false value to return.

```
console.log((name ? name : '') + (age ? age : ''));
```

For what you're doing though, I wouldn't concatenate a bunch of ternaries in this way.  Make an array and then join.

```
var parts = [];
if (name) {
  parts.push(name);
}
if (age) {
  parts.push(age);
}
// etc. etc.

console.log(parts.join(' '));
```

If you can use Array.filter (newer browsers), you can simplify your array, not needing all the `if` statements:  http://www.devign.me/javascript-tip-remove-falsy-items-out-of-an-array

Comment: I am stuck in the same problem as before, that I have extra spaces. For example if name is not there I will have **constant+' '+' '+age+' '+height**.

Comment: @Odin Not if you use the `join` method.  And, you can always add spaces after the variables above.  I just didn't for simplicity so I could explain a ternary to you.